# Determine if DateTime is in a given Date Range

Tags: c#, datetime

```
Aries          March 21 to April 20.
Taurus         April 21 to May 20.
Gemini         May 21 to June 21.
```

I need to print the Astrological sign of a user by getting the user's birth month and the date as inputs. How can I get the date range?

EX: March 21 to April 20

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't actually need to construct a datetime range to solve this.  A simple switch statement based on the month with a simple if statement for each month that returns one of two star signs will suffice.

```
   e.g
     switch (month)
     {
       case 1:
          if (day <20) return "Capricorn"; else return "Aquarius";
          break;
       case 2:
          ...
```

Comment: On a side note: I think the logic you are using to calculate the zodiac sign is wrong :-).. What you calculate there is the constellation behind sun. Zodiac sign is not that and it is the star constellation what ascend in the eastern horizon at the time of the birth.

Answer (score 9):

This is the implementation of the method:

```
    private string GetHoroName(DateTime dt)
    {
        int month = dt.Month;
        int day = dt.Day;
        switch (month)
        {
            case 1:
                if (day <= 19)
                    return "Capricorn";
                else
                    return "Aquarius";

            case 2:
                if (day <= 18)
                    return "Aquarius";
                else
                    return "Pisces";
            case 3:
                if (day <= 20)
                    return "Pisces";
                else
                    return "Aries";
            case 4:
                if (day <= 19)
                    return "Aries";
                else
                    return "Taurus";
            case 5:
                if (day <= 20)
                    return "Taurus";
                else
                    return "Gemini";
            case 6:
                if (day <= 20)
                    return "Gemini";
                else
                    return "Cancer";
            case 7:
                if (day <= 22)
                    return "Cancer";
                else
                    return "Leo";
            case 8:
                if (day <= 22)
                    return "Leo";
                else
                    return "Virgo";
            case 9:
                if (day <= 22)
                    return "Virgo";
                else
                    return "Libra";
            case 10:
                if (day <= 22)
                    return "Libra";
                else
                    return "Scorpio";
            case 11:
                if (day <= 21)
                    return "Scorpio";
                else
                    return "Sagittarius";
            case 12:
                if (day <= 21)
                    return "Sagittarius";
                else
                    return "Capricorn";
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tested this but it looks right... :)

```
    private static string GetStarSign(DateTime dateOfBirth)
    {
        int[] fromDate = { 21, 20, 21, 21, 22, 22, 23, 23, 22, 23, 22, 22 };
        string[] signs = { "Capricorn", "Aquarius", "Pisces", "Aries", "Taurus", "Gemini", "Cancer", "Leo", "Virgo", "Libra", "Scorpio", "Sagittarius", "Capricorn" };
        if (dateOfBirth.Day < fromDate[dateOfBirth.Month - 1])
            return signs[dateOfBirth.Month - 1];
        return signs[dateOfBirth.Month];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know I missed the boat on getting the accepted answer, but after giving [Kirk Broadhurst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/146077/kirk-broadhurst) a lashing I thought I better provide my own answer.

My reading of the question was that [chamara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367562/chamara) wanted something like this:

```
var birthDate = new DateTime(1923, 4, 20);
var starSign = StarSigns.GetFor(birthDate);

Console.WriteLine(starSign); // Taurus (April 20 - May 20)
Console.WriteLine(starSign.GetStartDate(2010)); // 2010/04/20 00:00:00
Console.WriteLine(starSign.GetEndDate(2010)); // 2010/05/20 23:59:59

var starSign1 = StarSigns.GetFor(10, 22);
var starSign2 = StarSigns.GetFor(10, 23);

Console.WriteLine(starSign1); // Libra (September 23 - October 22)
Console.WriteLine(starSign2); // Scorpio (October 23 - November 21)
```

So here are my classes:

```
public static class StarSigns
{
    private static StarSign[] _starSigns;

    static StarSigns()
    {
        var names = new[]
        {
            "Aquarius", "Pisces", "Aries", "Taurus",
            "Gemini", "Cancer", "Leo", "Virgo",
            "Libra", "Scorpio", "Sagittarius", "Capricorn", 
        };

        var days = new[]
        {
            20, 18, 20, 20,
            21, 21, 22, 23,
            23, 23, 22, 22,
        };

        _starSigns = (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, 12)
                      let name = names[i]
                      let startMonth = i + 1
                      let startDay = days[i]
                      let endDay = days[(i + 1) % 12] - 1
                      select new StarSign(name, startMonth, startDay, endDay)).ToArray();
    }

    public static StarSign GetFor(DateTime birthDate)
    {
        return (from starSign in _starSigns
                let startDate = starSign.GetStartDate(birthDate.Year)
                let endDate = starSign.GetEndDate(birthDate.Year)
                where startDate <= birthDate
                where endDate >= birthDate
                select starSign).Single();
    }

    public static StarSign GetFor(int birthMonth, int birthDay)
    {
        return GetFor(new DateTime(2010, birthMonth, birthDay));
    }

}

public class StarSign
{
    public StarSign(string name, int startMonth, int startDay, int endDay)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.StartMonth = startMonth;
        this.StartDay = startDay;
        this.EndDay = endDay;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public int StartDay { get; private set; }
    public int EndDay { get; private set; }

    public int StartMonth { get; private set; }

    public int EndMonth
    {
        get
        {
            return this.StartMonth + 1;
        }
    }

    public DateTime GetStartDate(int year)
    {
        return new DateTime(year, this.StartMonth, this.StartDay);
    }

    public DateTime GetEndDate(int year)
    {
        var nextStart = new DateTime(year, (this.StartMonth % 12) + 1, this.EndDay + 1);
        return nextStart.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromTicks(1));
    }

    public string Period
    {
        get
        {
            var startDate = this.GetStartDate(2010);
            var endDate = this.GetEndDate(2010);
            var template = "{0:MMMM dd} - {1:MMMM dd}";
            return String.Format(template, startDate, endDate);
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0} ({1})", this.Name, this.Period);
    }
}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: @`jmservera` - Yes, the API is pretty darn simple. The implementation is minimal, but robust. It would be hard to abuse this class too much. So, I agree that it is an excellent example of KISS in action.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that describes a star sign...

```
class StarSign
{
    public string Name {get;set;}

    public DateTime StartDate {get;set;}

    public DateTime EndDate {get;set;}

    public bool CoversDate(DateTime birthday)
    {
        return birthday <= this.EndDate && birthday >= this.StartDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: And how well will this work for Capricorn? December 22 -January 19??

Comment: I'm not very much clear on your answer.can u please explain bit more.

Comment: @`Kirk Broadhurst` - This doesn't answer the question as stated. I read it as requiring a function with this signature: `StarSign GetStarSign(int birthMonth, int birthDay)`. You solution doesn't take in to account that `DateTime` has a year and also a time component. If I passed in `#5/20/2010 11:23#` in to your `CoversDate` method I would not get any matching `StarSign`, even ignoring the issue with year.

Comment: Sheesh it's not ready to drop into your solution, it's just an example of a class that describes a star sign.

Comment: @Hightechrider It will work for Capricorn once it has some handling for years; and it needs to accept `day` and `month` parameters.  The point of the answer is that he could use a class to describe a star sign, and it's a 1 minute pull together of a class that starts to do that.