# Checking whether a user inputted date is between 2 dates within an IF statement? C#

Tags: c#, datetime

The user has inputted their birthday and I'm trying to find out whether or not if this date (I've called it UserBD) is between 2x dates (Date1 & Date2).

This is so that I can calculate the user's star sign based on their birthday month and day.

So far I've tried doing the following but It's clearly wrong as the days do not run endlessly upwards, they reset at the end of the month:

```
DateTime AquariusStart = new DateTime(1900, 01, 20);
DateTime AquariusEnd = new DateTime(1900, 02, 18);

if (userBD.Month >= AquariusStart.Month && 
    userBD.Month <= AquariusEnd.Month && 
    userBD.Day >= AquariusStart.Day && 
    userBD.Day <= AcquarisStart.Day)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Your Star Sign is Aquarius!");
}
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Could you just check `if(userBD >= AquariusStart && userBD <= AquariusEnd)`?

Comment: Sure, If you can tell me how to make the DateTime's Year not clash with the birthday? (I.E IF userBD.Year is 2000, the datetime's would be searching within 2000 or to ignore year altogether).

Comment: You just need to make the start/ends be the same year as your birthday and you can do any comparison you like

Comment: @WebDev-InTraining sure, just do `DateTime AquariusStart = new DateTime(userBD.Year, 01, 20);` and `DateTime AquariusEnd = new DateTime(userBD.Year, 02, 18);`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine if DateTime is in a given Date Range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939760/determine-if-datetime-is-in-a-given-date-range)

Comment: @TanyaPetkova I'm not sure the questions are asking the same thing, but the end goal of each is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare datetimes. So you can just do it like this:

```
var birthDay = new DateTime(1900, userBirthDay.Month, userBirthDay.Day);
if(aquariusStart <= birthDay && birthDay < aquariusEnd)
{
  //Do something.
}
```

Comment: How do I make the year of the DateTime sync with whatever the user's Birthday year is?

Comment: Edited it to use the same year. You have to create a new DateTime as DateTimes are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do:

```
DateTime AquariusStart = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 01, 20);
DateTime AquariusEnd = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 02, 18);

DateTime UserBd = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 02, 19);

if (DateTime.Compare(AquariusStart, UserBd) < 0 &&
    DateTime.Compare(AquariusEnd, UserBd) >= 0)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Your Star Sign is Aquarius!");
}
```

Comment: I always hate to use DateTime.Now. It might fail when the start is set on 2016 23:59:59 and the userbd in 2017 00:00:00.

Comment: @Carra Yes,you are right...but it's a very marginal case. Anyway, this was just to show the op `DateTime.Compare` :)